# calendar event display in Android

Tags: android, events, calendar

I have one doubt in Android. I have one Android application, in which I have to display calendar in one screen. On clicking on a particular date, I have to add or delete my particular items and events.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: here is a [TUTORIAL](http://caughtinthemobileweb.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/how-to-implement-calendarview-in-android/) of android calander view,& GIT hub source code availble [HERE](https://github.com/nevalla/CalendarView)...u need to customized it as per ur need Best of luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved . By using some [samples](https://github.com/nevalla/CalendarView) codes.